# Manual Install Apache 2.2.8 Configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I'm trying to install MySQL v 5,
Apache 2.2.8 and Catacomb 0.9.6 on linux and I'm quite confused at how files are laid out in Debian, this being the first time I'm using it.

I have installed MySql Server/Client already.

I need to do a manual install of Apache 2.2.8.

tar -xvzf httpd-2.2.8.tar.gz
cd httpd-2.2.8
./configure --enable-so
            --enable-dav
            --enable-dav-fs 
            --enable-dbd
            --with-mysql=
            --prefix=

make
make install

How can I find out the PATH_TO_MYSQL_INDLUE_DIR and PATH_TO_APACHE_INSTALL_DIR

Many thanks

Comment: I'm trying to install on Debian 6

Answer (score 0):

First, fix the make make install. Change it to.
make & make install

You tell apache where to install the compiled apache package with this flag. That's the same flag used to tell MySQL and PHP where to be installed.

--prefix=/var/apache2

Here's another example. You tell PHP where to find apache executable with this flag. You can lookup the flag needed for a source compiled of MySQL.

--with-apxs2=/var/apache2/bin/apxs'